# Why would the Babel REPL not run with a selected preset?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So take this JS code using an ES6 spread operator:

```
const a = { foo: 'bar' }
const b = { ...a }
console.log(b)
```

If I compile it with Babel like:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel temp.js --presets stage-0
```

Everything is as it should be. However say I want to run it from the babel-node REPL, starting it with:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets stage-0
```

then typing the above code at the prompt, after hitting enter on the spread operator line `const b = { ...a }` I get:

```
SyntaxError: repl: Modules aren't supported in the REPL (This is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error)
```

Why? :-)

Comment: *"So take this JS code using an ES6 spread operator..."* FWIW, it's neither ES6, nor an operator. It's object spread *syntax* that's currently a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread). ES2015 (aka "ES6") only had *array* spread syntax. Object spread is supported by the [`transform-object-rest-spread`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) plugin (listed as "experimental"), as well as in the `stage-2` and `stage-3` presets (and React roll-up plugins as object spread is very commonly used in React).

Answer (score 0):

Aha. So the problem seems to be that while `stage-0` will compile the spread syntax fine, I have the `transform-runtime` plugin in my `.babelrc` file. This causes the compiler output to involve `require` statements (for a utility function that deals with the spread in this case), which is what the error is about.

Question now is... How do I disable babel plugins at the CLI? Just commenting the line out when I want to run `babel-node` for now.